# How to scroll with large pages with jQuery onepage-scroll plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I found this great plugin called [onepage-scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html), which meets my needs, except for one thing. Some of my pages (`<section>` tags) can be larger than one screen. How can I customize it so that it only scrolls when it finished the "regular" scrolling, inside the section ?

I tried to change the css rule :

```
.onepage-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height:200%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

but it still scrolls to the next page, with one scroll movement.

I'm trying to make it scroll to the bottom of the section (height > 100%), then scroll to the next page.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead. There's an option called `scrollOverflow` which allow you to have scrolling inside section as you can see in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html)

Answer (score 0):

While it's a less ideal solution, we ran into the same issue and found that using an iframe works with jquery onepage scroller as a solution for providing this.